# Product decomposition into semisimple and unipotent parts of a connected, solvable, nilpotent Algebraic group $G$ (A. Borel’s LAG)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups, affine-varieties

Let $G$ be an algebraic group, i.e., an affine reduced, separated $k$-scheme of finite type with structure of a group.

In Armand Borel’s Linear Algebraic Groups Theorem III.10.6(4) says

> **Theorem 10.6 (3):** Let $G$ be a connected, solvable algebraic group. Then $G$ is nilpotent if and only if $G_s$ is a subgroup of $G$. In this case, $G_s$ is a
> closed subgroup defined over $k$, and $G$ is the direct product $G_s \times G_u$.

The subgroups $G_s, G_u \subset G$ are the semisimple resp. the unipotent parts coming from the Jordan decomposition.

The proof’s strategy is to show that $G = G_s \cdot G_u$ decomposes as a direct product of abstract groups and one observes that  $L(G_s) \cap L(G_u) = 0$, where $L(G_s)$ and $ L(G_u)$ are the Lie algebras of $G_s$ resp. $G_u$. Then the proof claims that this already implies that the product structure $G = G_s \cdot G_u$ holds as an algebraic group, because the canonical map $G_s \times G_u \to G$ is
bijective and separable.

A similar strategy is also used in the proof of part (4) of the same theorem to show that $G$ decomposes as a semi-direct product $G=T \cdot G_u$ of algebraic groups, where $T$ is a maximal torus.

Question: Why does separability of the bijective product map $G_s \times G_u \to G$ imply that it’s an ismorphisms of algebraic groups?

The book uses two notations of separability: a morphism $f: V \to W$ of algebraic varieties is separable if the field extension $K(W) \subset K(V)$ is separable. There is also a notion for separability for homogeneous spaces: the canonical projection $\pi: G \to G/H$ is separable if the induced map $(d \pi)_{1_G}: L(G) \to L(G/H)$ on Lie algebras at the neutral element $1_G$ is surjective. (Cor. II.6.7)

Since the map $G_s \times G_u \to G$ in my question is the canonical product map, I don’t see how one of these two seemingly unrelated definitions of separability can be applid here. Maybe it’s possible to interpret $G$ somehow as an orbit space/homogeneous space of $G_s \times G_u$. At all, if we want to see $G$ as an orbit space, then we should have a transitive $(G_s \times G_u)$-action on $G$ which coincides with the product structure $(u,v) \to u \cdot v:= m(u,v)$. But with respect to which action?

The most natural choices to define a $(G_s \times G_u)$-action on $G$ might be given via $((u,v), g) \mapsto u \cdot v \cdot g$ or  $u \cdot g \cdot v$.

Problem: an action $\Phi \colon H \times S \to S$ by a group $H$ on set $S$ must satisfy the “compatibility relation” with group multiplication $\Phi(h_1 \cdot h_2, s)= \Phi(h_1, \Phi(h_2, s))$ for all $h_1,h_2 \in H, s \in S$. But unfortunately the two natural guesses do not satisfy this rule. So either the argument in the book works differently or there is a less usual $(G_s \times G_u)$-action on $G$ applied. If the second case holds, I wonder why the book doesn’t write this action explicitly down.

And if there is some $(G_s \times G_u)$-action on $G$ established, how this would imply that $G_s \times G_u \to G$ is an isomorphism of algebraic groups? It seems that the central issue in the argument has to do with the separability, but I don’t see why the claim follows from it.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a complete answer, but to large to fit into a comment. My guess is that Borel means separability in the field sense.

Can you show that the morphism $f: G_s \times G_u \to G$ is finite (as a morphism of schemes)? Then it will be an isomorphism of schemes:

As $f$ is finite, it induces a finite, separable extension of function fields $k(G) \hookrightarrow k(G_s \times G_u)$. Because $f$ is bijective, and the extension is separable, it has degree $1$, so the function fields are actually the same.

Now if $\operatorname{Spec} A \subset G$ is open affine, its preimage $ \operatorname{Spec} B = f^{-1}(\operatorname{Spec} A)$ is affine (because $f$ is finite). So you get a finite extension $A \subset B \subset Q(B) = k(G) = Q(A)$. But since $G$ is smooth, $A$ is normal, i.e. integrally closed in $Q(A)$. Thus $A = B$.

Comment: Thank you, that's a nice approach. On finiteness of th product map: There is version [version of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-finite_morphism#Properties) of Zariski Main Theorem which I think could be applied here to the product map. (I'm rather happy about it , because all other versions of ZMT which were familar to me assumed properness) It's clearly quasi-finite, separated and of finite presentation (the 
spaces are all Noetherian). Then we can decompose to $G_u \times G_s \to Y \to G$
where first map is open immersion (and therefore birational) and the 
second finite.

Comment: To this one we apply your argument and conclude that it is
birational an d therefore the product map is birational too. And then the rest of your argument goes through.

Comment: Do you maybe have an idea how the separability of this map can be also deduced from the information 
that $L(G_s) \cap L(G_u) $ is zero ? $L(G_s) \cap L(G_u) $ is the kernel the induced map $L(G_s \times G_u) \to L(G)$ on the associated Lie algebras, so we are looking for a criterion like that $f$ is separable if the induced map on Lie algebras is injective. There is one (Prop II.6.7) (here from dimensional reasons the map on Lie algebras is injective iff surjective), but it uses group actions/orbit spaces and it's not clear to me which $(G_s \times G_u)$-action on $G$ should be considered.